# Converting python loop output into an array

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a python from loop output into an array. For example in the following code, I wanted the output as b = [6.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] but it gives the output as a column.

```
import numpy as np
j  = np.arange(1.5, 10.0, 2)
for m in j: 
    a = 2*m    
    if a <= 8:
        b = 2*a
        print(b)        
    else:
         b = 0.0
         print(b)
```

I have tried to define the output b as numpy.array but it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: You print one value after the other. You have multiple options - if it's just about how it's displayed, you could tell `print` to not print newlines and add a space. Otherwise, you'd probably want to save the values of `b` in a list and in the end print that - or do the whole loop as a list comprehension instead. Do you want to continue processing it later, or do you just care about printing? And will the loop remain this simple?

Comment: try like this `print(a, end=" ")` or `print(b, end=" ")`

Comment: Thank you. I want to continue processing it later. I put the print just to see how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to separate the creation of a data structure from whatever use you make of it, such as printing it, so you could create the `b` first, then print it:

```
import numpy as np
j  = np.arange(1.5, 10.0, 2)
b = []
for m in j: 
    a = 2*m    
    if a <= 8:
        b.append(2*a)
    else:
         b.append(0.0)
print(b)
```

As it happens, python's default is to print the array horizontally:

```
[6.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Or as a list comprehension: `[4*n*(n<=4) for n in j]`

Comment: Multiplying by the boolean, that's a neat trick, first time I've seen it :-)

Comment: tobias_k, must admit your solution is very unique!

Comment: Of course you can also use a more conventional list comprehension with a ternary expression like `[4*n if n <= 4 else 0.0 for n in j]` instead of that "multiply by boolean" trick.